# How can I use operator overloading function with a class in C++?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

I made a operator overloading function in a class. 
And I made another function which recalls the overloading function in the class.

I want to use the function which recalls the operation overloading function in main function so I wrote like this in the main function :

```
#include <iostream>
...

class Zealot {
    int x;

    ....

    void operator++() {             
    Zealot s; 
    s.x = -50;
    for (auto i = 0; i < 2; ++i, tail.push_back(s)); 
    }

    void Collision() {
        ...
        (*this)++;          // Error : C2676
        ...
    }
    ...
};

Zealot z;

int main() {
    z.Coliision();
}
```

I got Error C2676 so I couldn't compile the source.

What should I do to work it well?
I need your big helps.

Comment: The operator you've defined is the prefix form of `++`, so you'd invoke it like `++(*this);`. The postfix form is distinguished by a parameter (that's otherwise unused) of type `int`, so it's: `void operator++(int)`. Note that `operator++()` should normally return a reference to the just-incremented object.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin Thank you for your help!  I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have overloaded is the pre-increment operator.
What you are using is the post-increment operator.

You can either use the pre-increment operator:

```
++(*this);
```

or implement a post-increment oprator:

```
void operator++(int) { ... }
```

---

To be idiomatic, you should change the return values of those functions though.

```
Zealot& operator++() { ... }
Zealot operator++(int) { ... }
```

You can read more on operator overloading at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators.